# UIView disappears after orientation change

Tags: ios, ipad, uiview, sdk

I have the current problem:
 From an NSObject i'm creating / loading and animating a view:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"slidein" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];


[content.view setAlpha:1.0];
for (UIView *view in content.view.subviews) {
    [view setAlpha:1];
}
[content.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.contentEnclosure.size.width, self.contentEnclosure.size.height)];


[UIView commitAnimations];
```

My problem is that, when orientation changes, my animated view disappears. If i make my view appear again, the orientation settings (frame size) are correct, so i'm guessing, that the resizing mask is applied correctly, i just don't understand what needs to be done, for my view not to disappear.

Comment: When you assign frame for the view in orientation method, check whether the view is present. Had a same problem, assigning values only when it is presented solved it!!

Comment: I did eventually solve it, just forgot to update my post. Indeed, everytime you change orientation, you need to make sure that every subview of the frontmost view is visible and only then make yout changes.

Comment: Exquinoxe can you give more details as to how you solved it? I have a UISearchBar disappearing after orientation change on iPad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use NSLog and check the new `self.view.frame.origin.x` and `y` respectively after the orientation.

Then set the frame according to the requirement.

Also, check for resizing mask. Try using `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin`/`LeftMargin` to suit your requirements.